# Multiple actions for the one BarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to assign two actions to one BarButtonItem but I have a problem with the syntax `(bad receiver type 'NSInteger' aka 'long')` and I cannot compile my app. Here is the wrong code:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(myAction1)];
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(myAction2)];
```

I'm using `Xcode 5.1` and my target is `iOS 7.0.`

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This method doesn't exist. Call a method that will call the `Action1` and `Action2`

Comment: what your trying to do with two methods?

Comment: why do you want 2 actions to be called ? its simply not possible. you can call the 2nd action as a method inside 1st action instead. or use nsnotifications to let know anyone who has registered for the notification

Comment: Did any of these answers help you at all?

Comment: Hi JoeFryer, the answer that helped me is marked below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it that really your code ?

```
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(myAction2)];
```

isn't the receiver missing there ?

also a UIBarButtonItem can only have one target, if you want two actions getting called create a third one that will call the two others

```
- (IBAction)myAction3:(id)sender {
  [self myAction1:sender];
  [self myAction2:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign two actions to a `BarButtonItem`.

You can either call the second action in the `selector` method.

Or you can simply remove previous target and add new `target action` conditionally during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add multiple target/actions to a `UIBarButtonItem`.

You can add a bar button item with one target/action like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(myAction1)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem;
```

You'll then need to do something like call you second method from the one specified, or whatever is appropriate for your situation.